# adb: tap and input text

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to use "input tap" and "input text" via ADB:

```
input tap 400 730
input tap 60 410
input tap 150 490
input tap 120 300
input tap 120 420
input tap 130 180
input tap 130 180
input text name_of_the_apn
```

Tapping works fine, but the execution of the scripts gives back an error when it tries to input the text (see below). However, when I try to send the text outside of the script, it works fine. I already tried adding sleep between tapping and the text - with no effect.

Any hints? Thanks!

```
/mnt/.lfs: Function not implemented
/data/ste-debug/stedump: Operation not permitted
[1]   Killed                  input text name_of_the_apn
```

Comment: Do you have more information? Like where your script is located? Does the text input works when you do it manually?

Comment: Do you have UTF-8 chars in the text? When I tried to input text with `é` or `À` I had the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's nearly 7 years now, but I have to escape any spaces in the text when I use type from the commnand line (as opposed to being in the shell):

```
adb shell input text "Hi\ there\ this\ is\ dog"
```

and also be weary if it's a variable in bash

```
TEXT="Hi\ there\ this\ is\ dog"
adb shell input text "$TEXT" #make sure it's in quotes
```

I also think that maybe you had a variable on your terminal `name_of_vpn` but you were in the adb shell at the time, and the variable was not present, or you are not accessing that with `$`

It could also be that this has been fixed now.